# Why are the deleted answers to a post shown "modified" and prompted at the top?

Tags: support, feature-request, deleted-answers, new-contributors

This is commonly seen that when someone with 1 reputation point writes an all promotion answer, they get almost a dozen downvotes and then the answer gets deleted, either by a moderator, high-rep user or the owner themselves.

However that old question (because such people always tend to select highly seen question and accepted posts) gets prompted up at the beginning and stays there with the "modified by [user-name]" tag. Some examples of such recent posts:

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

Because of this, new questions go down in the list. I know those who wish to answer will hunt down unanswered questions, but this is sometimes highly inefficient. I get it we can't control users from posting such non-answer worthy answers, but then this feature can be implemented:

- When users modify their question or answer, it gets prompted at the top.
- Similarly, when an user deletes his/her answer or someone else's answer, they shouldn't be prompted. Like, if I answer to a question asked about an year ago, and then decide to delete it, then it (the post) should go back to its position in the list where it priorly belonged, and not on the top because I wrote and then deleted my answer.

I hope I was able to convey my suggestions/opinions properly.

Comment: If you want to propose something which would affect the software which powers the whole network then would it not be better to post on MetaStackExchange? I do not think our moderators can implement this just for this site.

Comment: I don't really know about the functioning of other sites, and whether or not they have this system of prompting. I have only been on Movies SE apart from here, and never really seen any such activity. So have to study the functioning before posting questions on Meta. Because all sites aren't as welcoming as they seem to be.

Comment: So in a nutshell, this is what happens when an answer is deleted and you don't have enough rep to see deleted answers. It is just an SE feature that remains the same across the SE network.